# Hide 'DD' (Day) from Date Drop-Down field

Tags: date, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm requesting multiple historic dates from applicants where the day 'DD' element of the date isn't required and they probably won't remember anyway. I'm using the Date Drop-Down field. Is it possible to not require the input field for the DD and display/collect only the MM/YY and still have the date field validate? I could hide it with CSS but need it to still validate obviously. Can I hide with a filter?

I've looked at [this](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gf_field_date/) but it doesnt mention MM/YY as a dateFormat string...

Have sent a support ticket to gravity forms but no reply

Comment: Recieved this back from GF support: There are no filters to remove day and month from a date field, note that the Date field is designed to require a full date, so hiding the inputs wouldn't be feasible either as the field would fail validation due to the missing data. in the meantime, I recommend you use a standard Drop Down field instead, where you can manually add the choices for the years you want to allow selection or use dynamic population to generate the choices dynamically using your own custom code.